# Julia parametric constructor and incomplete initialization

Tags: julia, parameterized-constructor

I'm new to programming in Julia (I'm coming from Java) and some Julia concepts are still difficult to understand to me. What I intend is to replicate this Java code:

```java
public class Archive<T extends Solution> {
  public List<T> solutions;

  public Archive() {
    solutions = new ArrayList<>() ;
  }
}
```

Then, I have defined the following Julia struct:

```
mutable struct Archive{T <: Solution}
  solutions::Vector{T}
end
```

and I would like to define a constructor to inialize empty archives. In the case of an external constructor, I think that the code would look like this:

```
function Archive()
  return Archive([])
end
```

Would it be possible to modify the constructor somehow to include the parametric type T?.

Comment: How would you like to use `T` in the constructor? Also, note that the first `struct` definition does not work on Julia (at least on version 1.8). If you add details and make code more runnable, the answers could be more on point.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to put it in context.

Comment: Now things are clearer. For the definition, you would want `struct Archive{T<:Solution} solutions::Vector{T} end`. It's usually best to leave things immutable, and you could still `push!` and modify elements of the `solutions` vector. In addition, in Julia the compiler infers types for you, so, there is no need to over-specify types (a common instinct for people from statically typed languages).

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely the constructor you want:

```
Archive(T::Type{<:Solution}=Solution) =Archive(T[])
```

Then you can write `Archive()` or `Archive(SomeType)` if `SomeType` is a subtype of `Solution`.

Note that your definition:

```
function Archive()
  return Archive([])
end
```

Is incorrect unless `Solution` is `Any` (and most likely it is not). You will get an error as `[]` is `Vector{Any}` and you require `Archive` to store subtypes of `Vector{<:Solution}`.